# Need a hand writing a MySQL query for related videos

Tags: mysql

So firstly here is the relevant table structure:

```
TUBE_VIDEOS
------
id
video_name

TAGS
----
id
tag_name
tag_type [either set to "actor" or "tag"]

TUBE_VIDEO_TAGS
----
tube_video_id
tag_id
```

I had asked a question a while back about how to use this data to get related videos: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383634/looking-for-advice-on-a-related-videos-query-on-a-tagged-video-system) -- this solution basically took videos with the most common similar tags to decide which were most similar.  Since then my database has been modified a bit to show what a tag is describing.  So for example "Tom Cruise" is set to tag_type "actor" whereas "explosion" is set to tag_type "tag".  What I'd like to do is adjust the query to weigh actors heavier than tags.  So essentially we would say to MySQL: Give me a list of video ID's with the most matching actors, in the event of tie use the most matching tags next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with just a lot of joins.  The following query starts with the current video `tv`.  It looks for all tags belonging to that video `tvt`.  Then it looks for all other video's sharing one or more tags `rtvt`.  For the related video's, it looks up the tag details `rt` and the video details `rtv`.

```
select      rtv.video_name
,           sum(case when rt.tag_type = 'actor' then 1 else 0 end) ActorCount
,           sum(case when rt.tag_type = 'tag' then 1 else 0 end) TagCount
from        tube_videos tv
left join   tube_video_tags tvt
on          tvt.tube_video_id = tv.id
left join   tube_video_tags rtvt
on          rtvt.tag_id = tvt.tag_id
and         rtvt.tube_video_id <> tv.id
left join   tags rt
on          rt.id = rtvt.tag_id
left join   tube_videos rtv
on          rtv.id = rtvt.tube_video_id
where       tv.id = <YourMovieId>
group by    rtv.id, rtv.video_name
order by    ActorCount desc, TagCount desc
```

After all the joins, you can count the various badge types and order by them.

Comment: Awesome, thanks man.  You made a small typo in the where clause that I fixed so I can only give you a 99% on the assignment :)